# Convert month to string in dataframe column and combine?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a df with three columns `name`,`month`.
I want to convert `month` to string. eg: 4 -> Apr and get last two digits of year. Eg 2019 -> 19 and combine both. eg: Apr20

```
            name        month   

    0       2020          4     

    1       2019          1     

    2       abc2020abc    3     

    3       abc2019abc    2
```

What i have done:
        For first two rows `0`,`1` to get ouput.

```
            df['month'] = df['month'].astype(int)
            df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
            df['year'] = df['number'].str[2:4]
            df['month'] = df['month'] + df['year']
            df = df.drop(['year'],axis=1)
```

So output for rows `0`,`1` is

```
            name           month

    0       2020           Apr20

    1       2019           Jan19
```

How can i seperate `20` from `abc2020abc`

My resultant output:

```
                name             month

        0       2020             Apr20

        1       2019             Jan19

        2       abc2020abc       Mar20

        3       abc2019abc       Feb19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import calendar
d = {'name': ['2020', '2019', 'abc2018abc', 'abc2017abc'], 'month': [4, 1, 3, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[a-zA-z]', '', x))
df['month'] = [calendar.month_abbr[int(y)] + x[2:] for x, y in zip(df['name'], df['month'])]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   name  month
0  2020  Apr20
1  2019  Jan19
2  2018  Mar18
3  2017  Feb17
```

**Other Approach**

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'[a-zA-z]', '')
df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(x)]) + df['name'].str[2:]
```